# c# application missing system.data.SQLite dll when publish

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

i've a problem in visual studio 2012 Desktop when i try to publish an application written in c#, in fact when i click on the setup.exe produced after publishing it says that it is missing system.data.SQLite even if in the references i set to copy locally.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have a copy of `SQLite.Interop.dll` in your bin folder what about your header seciton in the .cs file do you also have the following `using System.Data.SQLite;`

Comment: in bin->release i've got the dll including System.Data.SQLite except for sqlite.interop.dll

Comment: then make sure that the target machine either has it in a shared location that you should make and or point your reference to.. or set the property of the dll to copy Local = true

Comment: infact the dll are copy local=true!!!! :(

Comment: are you getting any errors when trying to publish.. do you have rights to push the code via the publish interface.. also is this a MSI application can you perhaps show the code that handles the entry point of your application if possible